# How I can I SELECT rows based on string containing ascii code 0x02?

Tags: mysql, select, ascii

I would like to locate all strings in a table containing the 0x02 character.
For clarity, I am looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%0x02%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hex literals? A `%` is `0x25`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 0x250225
```

Checking [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) reminds me that the `0x` syntax isn't strictly SQL standard, so maybe use `X''` instead

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE X'250225'
```

Comment: I just tested it with 25. Basically MySQL will use the whole Hex literal as it is. That's why simple injection attacks are so dangerous - trivially checking for `username LIKE 'admin'` is not enough.

Comment: Very nice, i will accept this answer (whenever the site let me).

Answer (score 3):

I would go with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOCATE(X'02', column) > 0
```

Comment: It seems Cylindric approach is somewhat faster (0.00 sec) vs (0.04)